# Download Multiple Files Using Async

Tags: android

I am trying to download multiple files using asyc but for some reason it only downloads one file successfully while all the other files are 0 bytes.

Only the file that is added first to the string array is downloaded successfully, the rest are written as 0 bytes on the SD card.

```
    class DownloadFileFromFTP extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

            //code
            //Read SharedPref
            String str_dirRestoredImage_open = sharedPref.getString("SharedPref_dirRestoredImage_open", "");
            int count;
            OutputStream output = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                int totalFilesChecked = arrListStr_Files_Checked.size();

                for (int i=0;i<totalFilesChecked;i++)
                {
                    // Output stream
                    file_name_remote_abs = stringArr_Files_Checked[i];
                    file_name_remote = file_name_remote_abs.substring(file_name_remote_abs.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(str_dirRestoredImage_open+"/"+file_name_remote);

                    Log.d("LOG", "zzz_i: "+i +" :"+file_name_remote);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;

                        publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                        // writing data to file
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            // Stuff that updates the UI
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Restored: "+file_name_remote, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // Stuff that updates the UI
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed To Restore: "+file_name_remote, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            //pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            //dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        }
    }
```

This is how I am calling it, where stringArr_Files_Checked is a string array of absolute URLs of files.

`new DownloadFileFromFTP().execute(stringArr_Files_Checked);`

Comment: You have only one input stream. But use it for all files. But after the first file downloaded that inputstream will not give data anymore. So 0 bytes for the following.

Comment: You should also open the url connection again for every new file. And specify the file at opening. Now you did not tell the server which file you wanted.

Comment: URL url = new URL(f_url[0]); You use only f_url[0]. Not [1], [2] ,...

Comment: So the loop should start before the 'try'.

Comment: @blackapps you have solved my issue, thank you, it's working now after following your comments